# ASP.NET Core Web API: how to assign value of null to a missing property in the request when parameter binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, property-binding, frombodyattribute

Using .NET 6.0. When trying to bind a parameter to a body of the request, I want to assign a value of `null` to the properties that aren't included in the request.

Consider the following:

```
public class SomeRequest
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property1")]
    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property2")]
    public string prop2 { get; set; }       
}

[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<SomeResponse> Post([FromBody] SomeRequest value1)
    {
    }
}
```

If I send the following request `{"property1":"abc"}`, I want `value1` to be `{"property1":"abc","property2":null}`, but instead I get an HTTP 400 with an error message that `property2` is required.

What is the best way to make it so that property2 is `null`?  I am pretty sure that it worked like this in .NET Core 3.1.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET 6 projects have nullable context enabled by [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types#setting-the-nullable-context) - meaning prop2 is treated as a non-nullable string.

To behave as you're expecting, either:

- Make prop2 nullable (`string?`)
- Disable the nullable context at the project level (`<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` in the csproj)

  - This *can* also be done at the source code level using pre-processor directives, but it isn't applicable in your use-case.